# how to retrive one field values into custom module without inheritence in odoo 10

Tags: odoo

How to retrieve `date_start` field values from `hr.contract` module to my custom module of all saved records.please help me

Please help with this code, how to write method to retrieve values.

```
contract = fields.Many2one('hr.contract')
join_date = fields.Date(string="Hire date", related='contract.date_start', store=True ,readonly=True)
```

Comment: Please put code into code boxes (and not into normal text).

Comment: contract=fields.Many2one('hr.contract')
join_date=fields.Date(string="Hire date", related='contract.date_start', store=True ,readonly=True)